# Substring on SSIS Variable expression

Tags: c#, variables, ssis, substring

I Have SSIS Variable Expression like this,

```
@[System::PackageName]+","+    
@[System::SourceName]+","+    
(DT_STR,15,1252) @[System::ErrorCode]+","+    
@[System::ErrorDescription]+","+    
(RIGHT((DT_WSTR,4)
DATEPART("yyyy",GetDate()),4)+"/"+    
RIGHT("0"+(DT_WSTR , 2)
 DATEPART("mm", GetDate()),2)+"/"+    
RIGHT("0"+(DT_WSTR,2)
DATEPART("dd",GetDate()),2)+"_"+    
RIGHT("0"+(DT_WSTR,2)
DATEPART("HH",GetDate()),2)+":"+    
RIGHT("0"+(DT_WSTR,2)
DATEPART("MM",GetDate()),2)+":"+    
RIGHT("0"+(DT_WSTR,2)
DATEPART("SS",GetDate()),2))+","+
 @[System::MachineName]
```

Now I want to get some string from `@[System::ErrorDescription]` which located before `at` , here's the sample of the `@[System::ErrorDescription]` value

`System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\blablablabl\yes.txt'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials)
   at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrlDelegate(Object xmlResolver)
   at System.Threading.CompressedStack.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.CompressedStack.Run(CompressedStack compressedStack, ContextCallback callback, Object state)`

what i've done is write the substring code on my variable expressions :

`SUBSTRING(@[System::ErrorDescription], 1, FINDSTRING(@[System::ErrorDescription], "at", 1)-1)+","+`

but its always give me an error , that substring value cannot be negative, whats wrong with my code?

Comment: It seems like you are going to great lengths to capture the error, and raising more errors in the process. Any reason you don't want to use built in Error logging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the result of `FINDSTRING(@[System::ErrorDescription], "at", 1)` is zero (i.e. string not found) then the last parameter to your substring expression becomes `-1`. It's a common problem.

Perhaps you could try evaluating whether it is zero, and only use Findstring if it isn't. I have split the expression below for clarity, but it should all be on one line. I don't have SSIS to test but see if it works.

I don't think you've posted your full expression but this should give you the idea.

```
FINDSTRING(@[System::ErrorDescription], "at", 1)==0
   ?
"Nothing Found"
   :
SUBSTRING(
    @[System::ErrorDescription], 
    1, 
    FINDSTRING(@[System::ErrorDescription], "at", 1)-1
)
```

Here's a link that describes conditional:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141680.aspx

I'm not convinced this is the full story, but try it and it will flush out your next issue.

Comment: I already changes the value but its give me diffrent error , so if i want remove the string after at, what kind of expression should i use..?